# Is there a limit to how many times an effect stacks?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

When I want to be super sneaky, I put on the full set of Sheikah gear (each part gives a bonus to Sneak) and then eat something that gives me sneak x3.

I'm starting to wonder... is there a limit to how much some effect can stack? With my setup I'm at Sneak x6, but did I already pass the max sneak effectiveness?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All buffs come in several stages. Look at these icons on your inventory screen:

[image]

See that line below it, how half of it is light grey and half of it is dark? That means you have a "level 1" buff out of a maximum two. Other things like Movement Speed have three segments like this.

Both equipment and consumables will add to this buff meter. There doesn't seem to be any added effect if you exceed the maximum.

Comment: Is there any list of what the max is for what effect? That max seems to be variable. It would also be a more complete answer :p

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't have a list (or a game) in front of me to check, but I'm fairly sure temperature and stealth are two and everything else is three. Look at food -- they will never buff you more than the maximum.

Comment: I did kind of rework that in my next question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304469/what-are-all-possible-effects-and-how-they-function I'm on a roll! I'm asking a ton of questions!

Comment: @Fredy31 For what it's worth, I believe that stealth caps out at 3, so wearing full Sheikah gear already puts you at the max stealth. I'd save the "Stealth x3" elixirs and food for when the situation requires you to use more potent armor since Sheikah set is quite weak armor-wise.